# Problem with correlog function in pgirness

Tags: r, coordinates, geospatial, spatial

I am trying to produce an autocorrelogram using output from the correlog function in pgirmess as is described [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/spatial-correlograms-in-r-a-mini-overview/).

My UTM coordinate data are: `structure(list(V1 = c(698073L, 698095L, 698274L, 697806L, 698602L, 
698632L, 697425L, 698272L, 698125L, 697935L, 698681L, 699287L, 
698687L, 698042L, 698052L, 697477L, 698096L, 698782L, 698203L, 
698113L, 698046L, 697923L, 699398L, 698143L, 698555L, 697973L, 
698042L, 698080L, 697918L, 698253L, 698687L, 698719L, 698079L, 
697982L, 698273L, 698995L, 698267L, 700678L, 698087L, 698887L, 
698599L, 698883L, 697947L, 698159L, 697464L, 697897L, 698867L, 
697775L, 698071L, 698043L, 698115L, 697979L, 697976L, 698064L, 
698024L, 698048L, 698200L, 698092L, 698328L, 697998L, 697772L, 
697957L, 698590L, 698789L, 698060L, 698071L, 699316L, 699094L, 
698633L, 699289L, 698089L, 697819L, 697894L, 698000L, 700218L, 
700004L, 699684L, 699743L, 726256L, 724864L, 725175L, 725438L, 
725778L, 700386L, 700740L, 700701L, 724204L, 724049L, 723872L, 
722994L, 698150L, 698197L, 698064L, 698285L, 698685L, 698716L, 
698316L, 698170L, 698920L, 699335L, 698273L, 698100L, 698605L, 
698089L, 697784L, 697693L, 697990L, 697809L, 697945L, 698108L, 
697945L, 697736L, 698567L, 699035L, 697651L, 698062L, 699035L
), V2 = c(1853363L, 1853581L, 1853596L, 1854098L, 1853795L, 1853764L, 
1853338L, 1853684L, 1853627L, 1853540L, 1853912L, 1853399L, 1853897L, 
1853236L, 1853744L, 1853505L, 1853458L, 1853926L, 1853736L, 1853858L, 
1853783L, 1853586L, 1853612L, 1853498L, 1853834L, 1853269L, 1853528L, 
1853639L, 1853533L, 1853503L, 1853897L, 1853704L, 1853685L, 1853638L, 
1853595L, 1853602L, 1853530L, 1852898L, 1853424L, 1853770L, 1853792L, 
1853859L, 1853586L, 1853708L, 1853603L, 1852869L, 1853973L, 1853898L, 
1853608L, 1853762L, 1853695L, 1853586L, 1853617L, 1853775L, 1853251L, 
1853162L, 1853693L, 1853603L, 1853654L, 1853463L, 1853532L, 1853392L, 
1853853L, 1853843L, 1853550L, 1853587L, 1853509L, 1853461L, 1853724L, 
1853506L, 1853535L, 1853643L, 1853807L, 1853556L, 1852417L, 1852815L, 
1853113L, 1852880L, 1785260L, 1786479L, 1786054L, 1785839L, 1785467L, 
1852514L, 1852029L, 1852391L, 1787745L, 1787746L, 1787926L, 1788326L, 
1853416L, 1853437L, 1853409L, 1853531L, 1853848L, 1853734L, 1853660L, 
1853465L, 1854071L, 1853365L, 1853577L, 1853698L, 1853878L, 1853286L, 
1853532L, 1853503L, 1853423L, 1854024L, 1854096L, 1853483L, 1853798L, 
1853664L, 1853804L, 1852806L, 1853503L, 1853304L, 1852806L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-117L))`

My response variable data are: `c(44.172, 43.975, 43.338, 43.854, 41.475, 42.414, 45.035, 44.025, 
43.278, 44.116, 44.606, 44.242, 45.682, 44.495, 42.732, 44.02, 
44.626, 43.535, 44.025, 43.409, 43.207, 43.46, 42.505, 45.348, 
42.495, 44.505, 43.636, 42.879, 42.086, 43.364, 43.667, 43.005, 
43.939, 44.813, 45.364, 42.475, 43.768, 42.909, 43.535, 44.949, 
43.187, 42.5, 43.495, 43.318, 42.561, 43.747, 42.005, 44.293, 
44.808, 43.702, 42.677, 44.566, 45.237, 43.859, 44.237, 43.909, 
44.596, 44.667, 44.04, 44, 42.192, 44.929, 42.949, 43.944, 43.53, 
43.298, 43.025, 43.424, 43.712, 42.51, 44.152, 44.01, 41.833, 
43.505, 44.646, 44.566, 42.929, 43.636, 44.54, 43.232, 43.182, 
42.217, 43.904, 42.864, 43.475, 42.323, 43.025, 43.429, 43.298, 
44.914, 42.884, 43.601, 44.475, 42.505, 41.268, 44.227, 42.955, 
42.833, 46.056, 44.293, 42.556, 43.717, 43.283, 43.086, 42.707, 
43.859, 42.884, 44.682, 41.551, 42.803, 45.242, 42.929, 42.848, 
44.288, 43.283, 43.288, 44.444)`

I tried:
`pgi.cor <- correlog(coords=coords, z=sp.rich$mean], method="Moran",nbclass=11)`, but this appears to have cause problem calculating distances between the duplicate coordinates:

> Error in dnearneigh(coords[-zero, ], breaks[i, 1], breaks[i, 2]) : non-positive number of rows in x

Therefore, I tried: `pgi.cor <- correlog(coords=unique(coords), z=sp.rich$mean[-c(31,117)], method="Moran",nbclass=11)` (because rows 31 and 117 are  duplicates of other rows).  However this gives me the same error result.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is caused rather by the spatial structure of your data. There are two clearly distinctive spatial  groups (with a threshold about 71e4 for `V1`), and `correlog()` works perfectly when applied to the biggest one.

Comment: @Ekatef Ah!  Thanks for pointing that out.  So if you managed to get it to work by performing the analysis separately on the two groupings?

Comment: Not completely :) The analysis works well on the largest group, but throws `Bad selection of class breaks, try another one...` for the smaller one. That is why I canno't propose an answer, but may suspect that the spatial structure of your data is somewhat special.

Comment: @Ekatef, Thanks for the clarification.  I found that I could reduce the nbclass in the correlog function and it worked.  I believe this is because the second "cluster" had fewer data points.